# System.ArgumentNullException in YummyFood project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am trying to finish a programming project that I have due for tomorrow. However, when I run it, the program stops when it's about to execute and throws a System.ArgumentNullException in my project.

```
var  foodByCategory = new ObservableCollection<Food>(
                foodList.Where(food => food.Category.Contains(foodCategory))
                );
```

In my RestService class, I am trying to get the foods value from null to receive the value assigned in another class, but it returns me to the System.ArgumentNullException before the program is able to finish the following code:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Food>> GetFoodsAsync(string uri)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Food> foods = null;
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    foods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Food>>(content);
                }
            }
```

I have tried researching online and I had no luck whatsover. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Here's the oneDrive link for the project if more information about the problem is needed:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lTBlFcJs0Q74SseM6nMDbnezpwugUT6Z/view?usp=sharing

I am testing out local databases for a programming project but it returns me a System.ArgumentNullException error

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?  Which element of that line is null?  Either use the debugger to figure this out, or look at the stack trace in the exception object

Answer (score 0):

Your project on the OneDrive is too big, so I create a sample to test the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` in the maui.

My Model class:

```
public class Person
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And convert the json:

```
string jsonText = "[{\"Name\":\"Person1\",\"Id\":20,\"Description\":\"hello\"},{\"Id\":220,\"Description\":\"word\"}]";
ObservableCollection<Person> persons = null;
persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Person>>(jsonText);
```

It worked fine. But when I used `persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Person>>(null);`, I will get **System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null.(Parameter 'value')**.

So you can try to debug to check the value of `string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and the url is right or not.